# Odoo crm to put field value inside attribute

Tags: xml, odoo, crm, odoo-10

I have a field called image_url for the CRM.

I want to display that image_url in a `<img` tag in the CRM.

`<field name="image_url"/>`

can I just use `<img src="<field name="pickup_time"/>" />`?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. Is this an xml file in /views (a odoo template) or in static/src/xml (qweb template)?

Comment: @Lucas — its just a view not a reporting. from user interface / views / crm.lead view or kanban view

Comment: Use this widget, but instead of working with the url you will have to upload the image `<field name="image_field" widget="image"/>`

Comment: I cant upload the image — I need it from the field, because data is added via API and not by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In `/odoo/odoo/addons/base/res/res_country_data.xml` I found this example:

```
<field file="base/static/img/country_flags/ca.png" name="image" type="base64" />
```

Give it a try!